# Laravel, insert multiple rows without using foreach

Tags: mysql, laravel, insert, save, eloquent

```
$input['activities'] = array(3,2,5);

foreach($input['activities'] as $activity_id){

    $user_activities = new User_activities;

    $user_activities->activity_id = $activity_id;

    $user_activities->user_id = Auth::id();

    $user_activities->save();

}
```

Is it possible to have a single line of script to do the above save for each statement in Laravel ?
Instead doing the save in `foreach`, is it possible to do it in a single line?

Comment: if you're happy with my answer below, you can accept it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the solution,

```
$activities = array(3,2,5);
$user->activities()->sync($activities);
```

User model will have the activities function like the following,

```
public function activities()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Activity', 'user_activities')->select(['activities.id'])->withTimestamps();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Just pass array of arrays to `Eloquent::insert()`:

```
$data = [];

foreach($input['activities'] as $activity_id) {
    $data[] = [
        'activity_id' => $activity_id,
        'user_id' => Auth::id()
    ];
}

Coder::insert($data);
```

Comment: Insert won't add created_at and updated_at time. That's need to be added manual. :)

Comment: $input[activities] contains array of values which needs to be inserted without using the foreach in separate rows.